# How to write Arabic to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I am trying to extract tweets with Python and store them in a CSV file, but I can't seem to include all languages. Arabic appears as special characters.

```
def recup_all_tweets(screen_name,api):
    all_tweets = []
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name,count=300)
    all_tweets.extend(new_tweets)
    #outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text,tweet.retweet_count,get_hashtagslist(tweet.text)] for tweet in all_tweets]
    outtweets = [[tweet.text,tweet.entities['hashtags']] for tweet in all_tweets]
  #  with open('recup_all_tweets.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
   #     f.write(json.dumps(outtweets, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

    with open('recup_all_tweets.csv', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
       writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=',')
       writer.writerow(["text","tag"])
       writer.writerows(outtweets)
   # pass

    return(outtweets)
```

Comment: If using Excel to view use `utf-8-sig` as the encoding and `newline=''` as an additional parameter to the `open` for `csv.writer`.

Comment: i had The same result also with newline ' ' and utf-8-sig

Comment: Then are the strings good before you write them? Garbage in garbage out.

Comment: Just use ```encoding='utf-8-sig' ``` instead of ```encoding='utf-8' ```

Answer (score 1):

Example of writing both CSV and JSON:

```
#coding:utf8
import csv
import json

s = ['عربى','عربى','عربى']

with open('output.csv','w',encoding='utf-8-sig',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.writer(f)
    r.writerow(['header1','header2','header3'])
    r.writerow(s)

with open('output.json','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    json.dump(s,f,ensure_ascii=False)
```

output.csv:

```
header1,header2,header3
عربى,عربى,عربى
```

output.csv viewed in Excel:

[image]

output.json:

```
["عربى", "عربى", "عربى"]
```

Note Microsoft Excel needs `utf-8-sig` to read a UTF-8 file properly.  Other applications may or may not need it to view properly.  Many Windows applications required a UTF-8 "BOM" signature at the start of a text file or will assume an ANSI encoding instead.  The ANSI encoding varies depending on the localized version of Windows used.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with
`f.write(json.dumps(outtweets, indent=4, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False))`

Comment: even under a json file the arabic language is unread :  "text": "\u0628\u0627\u064a\u0631\u0646_\u0645\u064a\u0648\u0646\u062e_\u0631\u064a\u0627\u0644_\u0645\u062f\u0631\u064a\u

Comment: yes thank you very much, tht's work with f.write(json.dumps(outtweets, indent=4, sort_keys=True,ensure_ascii=False)) with jsonbut the sae with the csv file

Comment: Yes edited my answer for some reason I put the opposite

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot and finally wrote the following piece of code:

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import numpy as np
itemsX = webdriver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"x1i10hfl")
item_linksX = [itemX.get_attribute("href") for itemX in itemsX]
item_linksX = filter(lambda k: '/p/' in k, item_linksX)
counter = 0
for item_linkX in item_linksX:
     AllComments2 = []
     counter = counter + 1
     webdriver.get(item_linkX)
     print(item_linkX)
     sleep(11) 
     comments = webdriver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"_aacl")
     for comment in comments:
         try:
             reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(comment.text)
             bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
             AllComments2.append(reshaped_text)
         except:
             pass
    df = pd.DataFrame({'col':AllComments2})
    df.to_csv('C:\Crawler\Comments' + str(counter) + '.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-16')
```

This code worked perfectly for me. I hope it helps those who haven't used the code from the previous post